# Prevent deleting files in output folder

Tags: python, arcpy, shapefile, copy

I am trying to transfer shapefiles by the number of shapefiles from one folder to another, But I want to keep the already existing files in the output folder. Is there any way? I  am using the following script:

```
import arcpy
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, basename
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
shpNumber=int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))
files = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp", "")
if not os.path.exists(outfolder):
    os.makedirs(outfolder)
n=0
nf=[]
for f in files:
    n+=1
    if n<=shpNumber:
        nf.append(f)
    # copy the file
for ff in nf:
    outpath=os.path.join (outfolder,'{ff}.shp'.format(ff=ff))

    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(ff, outpath)
    arcpy.Delete_management(ff)
```

Comment: I suggest to save with a different name and make old ones read-only if you happen to make a mistake with naming.  By your code it looks like you definitely want to overwrite the existing files `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`, avoid that if you don't like it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response: I tried True Overwright or without it, the same result. The problem is that I deal with a large number of files that were created, about 13,000 files for each of the thirty years, and sometimes in order to reduce the slowness of the computer, I need a mass transfer of the processed files in order to continue processing the rest. .
I am trying to automate data processing and therefore the option to create multiple folders does not allow software users to be completely comfortable with work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the file already exists using [`arcpy.Exists(output_path)`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/exists.htm) and **ignore the shapefile**:

```py
if arcpy.Exists(output_path):
    continue
```

Alternatively, you could also use [`os.path.exists(output_path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists). There are some other things I would like to point out:

- In your example, `ff` would be a file name including extension. Assuming `ff` is `lakes.shp`, then `'{ff}.shp'.format(ff=ff)` would evaluate to `lakes.shp.shp`.
- Use `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = False` to make sure that files are never overwritten. An error would occur in case there is a bug in the script to prevent accidental overwritten files.
- Consider using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) (as you see in my examples) instead of two loops

Here is an example using `arcpy.Exists(output_path)` along with the other suggested changes:

```py
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = False
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
max_number = int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))

if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

files = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp")

for i, file in enumerate(files, 1):

    if i > max_number:
        break

    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, file)

    if arcpy.Exists(output_path):
        continue

    arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(file, output_path)
```

---

Alternatively, you can also **change the file name** of the duplicate file:

```py
import arcpy
import os
import time

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = False
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
max_number = int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))

if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

files = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp")

for i, file in enumerate(files, 1):

    if i > max_number:
        break

    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, file)

    if arcpy.Exists(output_path):
        # replace with a better suffix... this is just an example
        timestamp = int(time.time()) 
        output_path = output_path.replace(".shp", f"_{timestamp}.shp")

    arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(file, output_path)
```

---

**Note:** Your solution, and both of my examples, takes the first n files (equals to `max_number`) from the result list of `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp")`.

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) does not specify the order of the list. **From all we know this could be completely random**.

You could use following code instead of `files = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp")` to ensure that the file order is always the same:

```py
unsorted_files = Path(arcpy.env.workspace).glob("*.shp")

# sorts unsorted_files list by modification time 
files = sorted(unsorted_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

However, `files`' elements are `Path` objects. You can access the file name with `file.name` (assuming `file` is a `Path` object). Here an example:

```py
import arcpy
import os
import time

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = False
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
max_number = int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))

if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

unsorted_files = Path(arcpy.env.workspace).glob("*.shp")

# sorts unsorted_files list by modification time 
files = sorted(unsorted_files, key=os.path.getmtime)

for i, file in enumerate(files, 1):

    if i > max_number:
        break

    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, file.name)
    
    if arcpy.Exists(output_path):
        continue

    arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(file.name, output_path)
```

Comment: Tank you very much it is helps me !!!

Comment: @YounesIdriss Please upvote and accept the answer by selecting the green check mark next to the answer if this answered your question.